# Using FCM push notification redirection not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I received multiple notifications from server. But problem is only the recent notification redirected to application. For all other notifications app is not open when click on notification. This happens only from my server. If I am sending multiple notifications from FCM console then all notification redirect to application. Why this happned?

Below is Json parsing code

```
     private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
                Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());
                try {

                    JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

                    String title = data.getString("title");
                    String message = data.getString("message");
                    boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
                    String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
                    String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
                    String payload = data.getString("payload");

                    Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
                    Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
                    Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
                    Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
                    Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
                    Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);

                    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                        pushNotification.putExtra("title", title);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                        // play notification sound
                        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
                    } else {
                        // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                        // check for image attachment
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                        } else {
                            // image is present, show notification with image
                            showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                        }
                    }

                    sendNotification(title, message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }

}
```

Here is notification generate code

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuPage.this, ComplaintList.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build();

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0, n);
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of notification? message or data ?

Comment: data type notification

Comment: share the code in which you are generating the notification after receiving.

Comment: @UsmanRana Please see the relevant code.

Comment: its because you set PendingIntent which automatically open app..

Comment: Can you please share your answer? What is another option?

Comment: And if it is because of PendingIntent, then why notification redirected correctly from firebase console?

Comment: only 1 notification is showing , which is the last one, right? issue is because you are using same notificationId all the time, which will override the old notification if it exists.

notificationManager.notify(0, n);

Comment: @UsmanRana Yes only last one is open

Comment: use different notificationId for each notification

Comment: already tried that solution, not working

Comment: Try PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this problem using below code for sending notification

```
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    notificationManager.notify(m, n);
```

Need to send different notification id all the time.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the folowing code will work for you:**

```
 private void sendNotification(String message, String contentTypeId, String contentId) {

            if (notifManager == null) {
                notifManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            }

            boolean isAppVisible = BaseActivity.count > 0;
            boolean isNotificationSound = true;
            //TODO: update count if app is open.
            if (isAppVisible) {
                if (isNotificationSound) {
                    try {
                        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                        r.play();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
                sendMessage(message, contentTypeId, contentId);
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                    assert notifManager != null;
                    NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID);
                    if (mChannel == null) {
                        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.app_name), importance);
                        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                        notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                    }
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    //              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.CONTENT_ID, contentId);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))                            // required
                            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())   // required
                            .setContentText(message).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) // required
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                } else {
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    //              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
                    intent.putExtra(AppConstants.EXTRAS.CONTENT_ID, contentId);
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))                            // required
                            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())   // required
                            .setContentText(message).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) // required
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                }
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                notifManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(contentId), notification);

            }
        }


        private void sendMessage(String message, String contentTypeId, String contentId) {

        }

        private static int getNotificationIcon() {
            return R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This Works For me Please try this one.

Comment: It's a good practice to provide a little explanation about your code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Ok.Sure i will try next time.